# Ionic AWS Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, typescript, ionic-framework, mobile

I am attempting to connect my Ionic mobile app to AWS backend and keep getting the same error.
Cannot find module "../aws-exports"

I've checked the node-modules folder and this is missing, but I have no idea what I should put here to fix this error.
The same code is in a lot of files in this app.

```
const aws_exports = require('../aws-exports').default;
```

I'm not sure what this code does exactly. If anyone has an experience with Ionic that could help that would be great.

Thanks,
Matthew.

Comment: Have you tried running `npm install aws-sdk` in your project directory?

Comment: Yeah, I see in another project that there is an aws-exports.js file with details about the server location and stuff like that.  Doesn't seem to create one for this project for some reason. I'm kinda lost with it all.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/enhanced-javascript-development-with-aws-mobile-hub/

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the steps in the README. Specifically, the section on [Creating AWS Mobile Hub Project](https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/tree/master/ionic-angular/official/aws#creating-aws-mobile-hub-project). When you init the AWSMobile project, `aws-imports` is created for you.

P.S. `aws-amplify` has introduced some changes in the last couple of weeks that cause the ionic starter to not work. Follow [these steps](https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/issues/88) to fix the errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you sign into your Amazon console and you go to your Mobile Hub.
https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub/home#/

You can **click on your project** and it will return the ID in the URL as follows:
https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub/home#/`YOUR_ID_HERE`/build

You can then run the following command:

```
awsmobile init <mobile-hub-project-id>
```

The AWS Mobile Hub scripts should then fetch all relative dependencies and make the appropriate installations to rectify the issue.